# How to split regular and error output into files from SQLPlus using Bash?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

My main goal is to split the output from SQLPlus* into two log files: one receives only the commands being executed/the outputs and the other one receives only errors issued by Oracle system while executing the SQL statement.

The main script I'm working on has the line:

`sqlplus -s ${username}/${password}@${tns_alias} <<< EOF 1>$TEMPORARY_FOLDER/output-logs/${script}-output.log 2>$TEMPORARY_FOLDER/error-logs/${script}-error.log;`

Since it'd be harder to contextualize my problem through it, I've made an shorter script to make my tests:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_credentials() {
    exit_status_code=1;
    until  [ $exit_status_code -eq 0 ]; do
      read -r -p "Username: " username;
      read -r -s -p "Password: " password && echo;
      read -r -p "TNS: " tns_alias && echo;

      echo -e "\nVerifying credentials...";
      sqlplus -s /NOLOG << EOF 2>>error.log 1>>output.log 
        SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
        CONNECT ${username}/${password}@${tns_alias};
EOF
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Credentials authenticated successfully!";
        exit_status_code=0;
      fi;
    done;
  echo;
}

get_credentials
```

When the code is executed and I insert some wrong credential, the error output isn't redirected to `error.log` file but rather to `output.log` file. Why is this happening? Is it even possible to make what I want to? That is, separate outputs according to its nature (regular log or error log), considering it is totally depended on SQLPlus.

Comment: The script code is correct. If sqlplus doesn't write errors to stderr, there's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. sqlplus does not redirect its errors to the standard error and also stdout. Please check this [link](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/135813-redirect-output-error-2-different-files.html). You need to parse it afterwards.